# Leaflet: how many tiles are loaded when map is loading for the first time?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I integrated Leaflet OSM (Open Street Maps) to my application and the map view is loading.

```
this.map = leaflet.map(this.mapContainer.nativeElement, {
      preferCanvas: true,
      zoom: 14,
      zoomAnimationThreshold: 0,
      renderer: leaflet.canvas()
    });
```

I want the count of tiles loaded when map is loaded.

I checked official [docs of leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#tileimage-display) but didn't find regarding the count.

do I need to calculate the count of tiles loaded according to screen? if yes then how?

Comment: do you want do get the cout of the current displayed / loaded tiles or the count of all ever loaded tiles?

Comment: @FalkeDesign cout of the current displayed / loaded tiles only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function getTilesCount(){
    var tileLayers = map.getPane('tilePane').children[0].children;
    var idx = -1;
    var tileCount = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < tileLayers.length; i++){
        var tile = tileLayers[i];
        if(tile.style.zIndex >= idx){
            idx = tile.style.zIndex;
            tileCount = tile.children.length;
        }
    }
    return tileCount;
}
```

It counts the DOM tiles in tile container with the highest z-Index

Answer (score 0):

Leverage the [`tileload` event of `L.TileLayer`s](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#gridlayer-tileload), e.g.

```
var tileCount = 0;
myTileLayer.on('tileload', function() { tileCount++ });
```

If you want to count tiles on *initial map load*, you should make sure to hook an event handler for the corresponding `tileload` event *before* the tilelayer starts loading, and stop counting when the tilelayer reports all tiles loaded (via [its `load` event](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tilelayer-load)), e.g.:

```
var map = L.map('leaflet', {
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 3 
});

// Create a tilelayer but *do not* add it to the map *yet*
var myTileLayer = 
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        });

var tileCount = 0;

// Hook up event handlers...
myTileLayer.on('tileload', function(){ tileCount++; });
myTileLayer.once('load', function(){ 
    // Do something with the number of loaded tiles
    window.alert(tileCount);

    // Detach all event handlers for the 'tileload' event since they're not needed anymore
  myTileLayer.off('tileload');
});

// Now that the event handlers are ready, add the tilelayer to the map
myTileLayer.addTo(map);
```